# make layout flexible in Recyclerview

Tags: android, layout

How to Achieve this layout shown in below image Please suggest me how to make layout at run time while my contain is loading directly from web service.

[image: Inshort App Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FlexboxLayoutManager for this, here is the snippet

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager();
layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

And in Gradle file you will have to compile this dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha3'
```

for more you can check this link [here](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)